# Incorrect value being returned from static method

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I'm having an issue with getting mouse input in LWJGL. Here's my code to get input:

```
public class MouseButInput extends GLFWMouseButtonCallback {

    public static boolean[] buttons = new boolean[65536];

    public static boolean isButtonPressed(int button) {
        return buttons[button];
    }

    public static boolean isButtonPressedRelease(int button) {
        boolean isPressed = buttons[button];
        if (isPressed) System.out.println("TEST 1");
        buttons[button] = false;
        if (isPressed) System.out.println("TEST 2");
        return isPressed;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, int button, int action, int mods) {
        if (action == GLFW_PRESS) buttons[button] = true;
        else buttons[button] = false;
    }
}
```

I was originally having an issue where when I clicked once, the `isButtonPressed()` method would return true for the next 5-10 updates because that's how long the button was actually held down. I created the `isButtonPressedRelease()` method to return true if the button was pressed and then set the button's value in `buttons` to false, so it wouldn't return true the next update. The problem is, it never seems to return true. I put in a few print lines to test if `isPressed` was true before I return it, which it was. If I switch back to using the `isButtonPressed()` method everything works as expected.

Not sure what I'm missing here... my guess is that it has something to do with mixing the static and non-static methods/variables?

Also, here is where I call the method from:

```
public void update() {
    isHover = (aabb.intersectsPoint(MousePosInput.pos.x, MousePosInput.pos.y)) ? true : false;
    if (MouseButInput.isButtonPressedRelease(GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_1) && isHover && onclick != null) {
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Button clicked.");
        onclick.actionPerformed(evt);
    } else {
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For clarification, when my application is launched the following code is run:

```
private GLFWMouseButtonCallback buttonCallback;
...
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new KeyInput());
```

Now, invoke is automatically called each time a mouse button is pressed. I am currently NOT using `isButtonPressed()`, only `isButtonPressedRelease()`. Those two methods are used outside of the MouseButInput class to see if a key is pressed, the only difference is `isButtonPressedRelease` needs to go into the `buttons` array and set the value for the button that I am checking to false.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `invoke` and `isButtonPressed` are never used in this code. When are you expecting them to be called?

Comment: Invoke is called anytime a button is pressed, its set up using `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, buttonCallback = new MouseButInput());` And I'm not using `isButtonPressed()` in the code I showed, but regardless, I need `isButtonPressedRelease()` to work.

Comment: Then you need to include that code in the question. We can't help you diagnose the code if there are parts missing. Make sure you have a [mcve].

Comment: I made some edits that will hopefully clear up any confusion. I added the only code necessary to get my MouseButInput class working.